# Why is the limit in the random32_unbiased function different between the comments and the actual code?

Tags: cryptography, privatekey, source-code-documentation

I'm talking about this [specific function](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/9aab19f349433687c7aaf2c1cbc5751e5912c0aa/src/crypto/crypto.cpp#L123-L137):

```
void random32_unbiased(unsigned char *bytes)
  {
    // l = 2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493.
    // l fits 15 times in 32 bytes (iow, 15 l is the highest multiple of l that fits in 32 bytes)
    static const unsigned char limit[32] = { 0xe3, 0x6a, 0x67, 0x72, 0x8b, 0xce, 0x13, 0x29, 0x8f, 0x30, 0x82, 0x8c, 0x0b, 0xa4, 0x10, 0x39, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf0 };
    while(1)
    {
      generate_random_bytes_thread_safe(32, bytes);
      if (!less32(bytes, limit))
        continue;
      sc_reduce32(bytes);
      if (sc_isnonzero(bytes))
        break;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the comment states that the limit should be:
`l = 2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493`

If we perform that simple addition, we'd end with the number:
`l = 7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989`

However, when I convert the limit specified in the cpp codebase to decimal value:

```
static const unsigned char limit[32] = { 0xe3, 0x6a, 0x67, 0x72, 0x8b, 0xce, 0x13, 0x29, 0x8f, 0x30, 0x82, 0x8c, 0x0b, 0xa4, 0x10, 0x39, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf0 };
```

I end with a totally different integer of 256 bits, that in decimal would be:

`limit = 102863016385298801202249955531570426590943090958063650200743214154731025858800`

Why is there an inconsistency between the limit in the comments and the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there an inconsistency between the limit in the comments and the actual code?

There's no inconsistency.

```
l = 2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493
limit = l * 15 = f00000000000000000000000000000013910a40b8c82308f2913ce8b72676ae3
```

Reversed byte order:

```
e36a67728bce13298f30828c0ba41039010000000000000000000000000000f0
```

The same as defined in:

```
limit[32] = { 0xe3, 0x6a, 0x67, 0x72, 0x8b, 0xce, 0x13, 0x29, 0x8f, 0x30, 0x82, 0x8c, 0x0b, 0xa4, 0x10, 0x39, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf0 }
```

Comment: Amazing! Then I was missing the hex conversion. Would you happen to know where in the code the hex is reversed?

Comment: I think you also missed that `limit` is `"15 l"`.